# Добрый день, подскажите, как создать ограничение по возрасту в форме регистрации, пользователь заполняет форму "age'' отображаем сообщение нет 18

Tags: php

```
 <form action="/" method="GET">
<div>
    <label for="">Please enter a name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name">
</div>
<div>
    <label for="">Please enter your age</label>
    <input type="text" name="age">
</div>
 <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
 </form> 
  <?php 
  //создавал цикл if который выводит сообщение, но без переменной
   $age = 18 
   if($age == 18){
    продолжаем сценарий
   }else{
   echo 'вы слишком молоды'; //но как получать результат из формы? ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При отправке формы методом GET все данные из формы хранятся в переменной `$_GET['key']`, где key - название поля.

Так что для получения возраста из формы в вашем случае необходимо написать:

```
$age = $_GET['age'];
```

Но я рекомендую отправлять формы методом POST, в таком случае данные будут храниться в переменной `$_POST['key']`

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало!)